# How can I perform face recognition with openbr on a rotated image?

Tags: face-recognition, openbr

Using openbr such as

```
br -algorithm FaceRecognition -compare pictures.gal photo csv
```

I can get consistent results as long as the persons face in the photo is not rotated. I can't seem to get openbr to recognize a face that is rotated 90 degrees. Does openbr have some way of compensating for rotated photos? I considered rotating the photo myself with imagemagick but I don't think it would be possible to know which direction to rotate.

Comment: Try `convert image.jpg -auto-orient result.jpg` if the EXIF information is present in your images.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Ah yes I believe that's an acceptable solution. Would you like to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the EXIF information is still present in your image, you could maybe let ImageMagick autorotate the image upright for you as follows:

```
convert image.jpg -auto-orient result.jpg
```